# How can i use PHP to show datetime without seconds

Tags: php, sql, datetime

How can i change ex. 2009-01-14 06:38:18 to 2009-01-14 06:38?
the column type is `DATETIME`. i dont wanna use `SELECT DATE_FORMAT`

How could I do it with PHP?
`date("M-d-Y H:i", $userow['regdate'])` gives:

```
Strict Standards: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. Please use the date.timezone setting, the TZ environment variable or the date_default_timezone_set()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [date_default_timezone_set()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) before, as your error says.

Answer (score 0):

The error message just suggest you specify your timezone so you end up printing the correct date for your intended audience. Other than that, date() expects a timestamp as it's second argument so that's why converting the string MySQL returned to an int with strtotime() definitely helps.